# How to set up Bootstrap 3 horizontal thumbnail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [this demo](https://www.bootply.com/lotpXvCX8N). Why am I unable to set a horizontal thumbnail to display caption on right of image of thumbnail instead of default down the image?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://v1.myhometheme.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cozy-apartament.jpg" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure is right but the image is huge

http://jsfiddle.net/ngb3n9gx/

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to set the image width